# SOAP API call OAuth 2.0 error

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, oauth2

I'm using the postman to test one SOAP API call that is resulting on error 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access

I have created a new OAuth 2.0 Package an retrieving one token from POST
`https://mc2-xxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/` with the client_id and client_secret of the created package and the `"grant_type": "client_credentials"`. Then I map that token to the `accessToken` variable of my environment that I'm using on the soap call

SOAP POST endpoint `https://mc2-xxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com`

I want to retrieve the field Value from one DE with External Key Test_API

SOAP body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth>"{{accessToken}}"</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Test_API]</ObjectType>
              <Properties>Value</Properties>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

On the Header section of the Postman I have just `Content-Type = text/xml`

Is my SOAP request incorrect? I'm using the SOAP endpoint indicated by the Get Token request.

Comment: First I would verify that you are using the SOAP/REST endpoints returned in your OAuth call (also in admin in UI) and verify that is the endpoint you are using. V2 will only work on these endpoints, not the legacy ones. Outside of that, I know it was a known issue that SOAP could not use V2 token, but it seemed to have been resolved. Perhaps it is that this solution has not yet been pushed to your stack/instance yet.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, many thanks for your reply. I was using incorrectly one GET instead of POST. I have edit my query. Now I'm getting error 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access. My instance is S10. I have check the endpoints returned by the get token and are the same that I'm using to perform the post. Any ideas?

Comment: After some test I was able to see that It was missing the SoapAction on my header. Now is working

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, for others to find